# Add svg filter to paths created by leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, svg

If I were to create a simple inline svg, I could modify paths to have a drop shadow or a blur by creating a `<filter>` within a `<defs>` grouping. However, Leaflet dynamically generates the SVGs it uses to display paths, and I'm not sure how to add a filter after the fact.

**Failed Ideas:**

- I've tried using jQuery to append a defs to the SVG after the fact:

Like this:

```
    $("svg").prepend("<defs><filter id='dropshadow' height='130%'><feGaussianBlur in='SourceAlpha' stdDeviation='3'/> <!-- stdDeviation is how much to blur --> <feOffset dx='2' dy='2' result='offsetblur'/> <!-- how much to offset --><feMerge><feMergeNode/> <!-- this contains the offset blurred image --><feMergeNode in='SourceGraphic'/> <!-- this contains the element that the filter is applied to --></feMerge></filter></defs>");
```

And then specify the location of the defs in my CSS, like this:

```
    filter: url("../index.html#dropshadow");
```

- Have the `<defs>` / filter definition already inline in the html above the map element, and then reference the filter definition from the svg via a the CSS filter URL.

My code (inline above the leaflet map div):

```
    <svg xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; version="1.1">
        <defs>
            <filter id='dropshadow' height='130%'>
                <feGaussianBlur in='SourceAlpha' stdDeviation='3'/> <!-- stdDeviation is how much to blur --> 
                <feOffset dx='2' dy='2' result='offsetblur'/> <!-- how much to offset -->
                <feMerge><feMergeNode/> <!-- this contains the offset blurred image -->
                <feMergeNode in='SourceGraphic'/> <!-- this contains the element that the filter is applied to --></feMerge>
            </filter>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest going with your second approach of putting your svg markup in-line. I think your jQuery prepend method doesn't work because you need to create `<defs>` and other children of `<svg>` elements using document.createElementNS and jQuery is probably using document.createElement.

Anyway, the piece you're missing is applying your filter to your svg, which you could do two ways.

[CSS approach](http://jsbin.com/jilafu/1/):

```
div.leaflet-overlay-pane svg > g path {
  filter: url(#dropshadow);
}
```

[$ approach](http://jsbin.com/vegavo/1/) (put this after you add your geojson to your map):

```
$("div.leaflet-overlay-pane svg > g path").css({
  filter: "url(#dropshadow)"
});
```